# Is there a way to check if two lists of objects contain only the same type of object in Python?

Tags: python, list, compare

For example:

```
class someObject:
    def __init__():
        pass
objone = someObject()
listone = []
listone.append(objone)
objtwo = someObject()
listtwo = []
listtwo.append(objtwo)
```

Both lists have the same kind of object, namely someObject, and I want to know how I can check this. The above scenario should return True, as both lists have the same kind of object, but if listone was empty or, say, had a String *along with* the object it would return False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `check_lists` functions does the following, it checks if the lists or of same length first, then it `zips` through the elements in the list and compares if the `type` of `i` is the same as `j`. Only if all are `True` you get `True` else `False`.

The example below shows some tests.

```
class someObject:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
objone = someObject()
listone = []
listone.append(objone)
objtwo = someObject()
listtwo = []
listtwo.append(objtwo)

def check_lists(listone, listtwo):
    return len(listone) == len(listtwo) and all(isinstance(i, someObject) and isinstance(j, someObject) for i, j in zip(listone, listtwo))

print(check_lists(listone, listtwo)) # True
listtwo.append('string')
print(check_lists(listone, listtwo)) # False
```

Edit :
Changed `is` to `and`. @chepner 's comments explains on this.

Comment: I have no idea how this works , but it works. Thank you kind stranger

Comment: I have added a brief explanation, you can mark it as solved if it helped you

Comment: This doesn't accommodate subclasses.

Comment: `isinstance` doesn't? @chepner

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using `is` to compare the types of `i` and `j`. I would use `and` instead of `is` here to verify that both objects have the same type. `False is False` would be true, though it indicates the two objects do *not* have the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Use type()

```
>>> type(objone) == type(objtwo)
True
>>> type(objone) == type("some String")
False

# here is how

>>> list_one_types = [type(i) for i in listone]
>>> list_two_types = [type(i) for i in listtwo]
>>> list_one_types = set(list_one_types)
>>> list_two_types = set(list_two_types)
>>> list_one_types
{<class '__main__.someObject'>}
>>> list_two_types
{<class '__main__.someObject'>, <class 'str'>}
>>> list_one_types == list_two_types
False
```

Comment: That works for single objects, but they are in a list in my example.

Comment: This doesn't accommodate subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.chain`, `all` and `isinstance`.

```
from itertools import chain

if all(isinstance(x, someObject) for x in chain(listone, listtwo)):
    ...
```

If you don't know ahead of time which type is involved, just get the first object (after verifying that both lists are non-empty):

```
if listone and listtwo and all(isinstance(x, type(listone[0])) for x in chain(listone, listtwo)):
    ...
```

Comment: `chain` is clever :D